# Rails server not working (even though I am in the correct directory)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

I created a new app in desktop/maps.
I haven't linked it to github or anything and am just working locally. 
I have previously used the rails s function and it worked perfectly however now that I want to pickup where i left off it now says:

```
Sachins-MacBook-Pro:maps sachinkaria$ rails s
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]                                      # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                                         # Default: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]                                # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]                              # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile], [--no-skip-gemfile]              # Don't create a Gemfile
      [--skip-bundle], [--no-skip-bundle]                # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -O, [--skip-active-record], [--no-skip-active-record]  # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets], [--no-skip-sprockets]          # Skip Sprockets files
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]                              # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                                         # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]                          # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                                         # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript], [--no-skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev], [--no-dev]                                # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge], [--no-edge]                              # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  -T, [--skip-test-unit], [--no-skip-test-unit]          # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--old-style-hash], [--no-old-style-hash]          # Force using old style hash (:foo => 'bar') on Ruby >= 1.9

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]                    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet], [--no-quiet]      # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip], [--no-skip]        # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help], [--no-help]        # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version], [--no-version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

Please note i am in the correct directory and I've have previously run the started the server.

Comment: maybe you want the `rails server` command rather than `rails new`

Comment: i am using the rails server command but it doesn't seem to detect a rails app in the directory

Answer (score 2):

Which directory are you in? Running `rails server` will return the syntax banner you pasted unless the file `config.ru` is in the same directory.

Comment: im in the directory correct directory e.g rails new maps > cd maps >rails server, config.ru is in the folder

Comment: That's odd. Can you create another test app in another directory and have `rails s` start properly?

Comment: If you're on Rails 4, try `./bin/rails s`

Comment: i've created another test app and it works fine, i tried the ./bin/rails s and got this error

"Could not find nokogiri-1.6.6.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems."

then i tried bundle install and get this:

"extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/extensions/x86_64-darwin-10/1.9.1-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out"

Comment: Typically a nokogiri build failure is due to a lack of `libxml2`. Install that, then `bundle install`, then try to start the server.

Comment: "achins-MacBook-Pro:maps sachinkaria$ brew install libxml2
Warning: libxml2-2.9.2 already installed"

Comment: The exact missing piece should be listed in `gem_make.out`

Comment: got it working using - gem install nokogiri -v 1.6.5 -- --use-system-libraries and then bundle install etc. now rails server works! thanks for your help mate

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rails 4+, regenerate your app's `bin/` directory executables:

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

These are versioned like any other source code, rather than stubs that are generated on demand with bundler. Using the regenerated executable should solve the problem.